How to create a timechart in splunk for the timestamp and extracted field?
I'm trying to create a timechart for timestamp of each event and TotalTimeTaken value in splunk.
My query:
index=XYZ  Total Time Taken  StudentController   
| rex "Total Time Taken: (?<TotalTimeTaken>[^,}]+)"
| timechart  TotalTimeTaken limit=5

Expected data table:



_time
TotalTimeTaken




2024-04-03T06:27:07.371-04:00
52 ms


2024-04-03T06:27:07.328-04:00
23 ms


2024-04-03T06:27:07.306-04:00
24 ms


2024-04-03T06:27:07.293-04:00
74 ms


2024-04-03T06:27:07.283-04:00
22 ms



But the timechart is not coming as expected. Need the exact values of TotalTimeTaken instead of count.
Is there any way to build the chart from the existing dataset?
I have created the dataset as shown in the above table. How to use this table dataset and create a line chart out of it?

@RichG.. Can you please suggest me out with the splunk query to create a visualization chart ?

I see two problems here.  The first is the timechart command requires numeric data, but the TotalTimeTaken field is a string because of the "ms".  That's easy to handle.  The second problem is the timechart command has a minimum resolution of 1 second so it is unable to graph 5 values in the same second.  Handle that by using an aggregation function (max, min, avg, etc.).
Here's a run-anywhere example using the sample data.
| makeresults 
| eval _raw="_time  TotalTimeTaken
2024-04-03T06:27:07.371-04:00   52 ms
2024-04-03T06:27:07.328-04:00   23 ms
2024-04-03T06:27:07.306-04:00   24 ms
2024-04-03T06:27:07.293-04:00   74 ms
2024-04-03T06:27:07.283-04:00   22 ms"
| multikv forceheader=1
| eval _time=strptime(time_,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3N%:z")
``` Above sets up test data.  Skip IRL ```
``` Strip out the unit label ```
| rex field=TotalTimeTaken "(?<TotalTimeTaken>\d+)"
| timechart values(TotalTimeTaken) limit=5


If we have large dataset, how to handle it in query ?

The size of the data set doesn't matter.  All you need are the last two lines and they work with any amount of data.  The values function has some limitations, but the aggregation functions do not.

Thanks a lot for the query and the suggestion
